# Have I created and mounted this raid array correctly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, fdisk

So I am working out how to add a new raid1 array to our server as we have a raid1 array which is almost full. I have replicated our server setup in a virtual machine and attempted to add a raid array but I want to check I have done everything correctly.

Before adding the raid array I have a setup like so:

`` lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME      SIZE  TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       100G  disk 
|-sda1     10G  part 
|  `-- md0 10G  raid1 [SWAP]
`-sda2     90G  part
   `-- md1 90G  raid1 /
sdb       100G  disk 
|-sdb1     10G  part 
|  `-- md0 10G  raid1 [SWAP]
`-sdb2     90G  part
   `-- md1 90G  raid1 /
sdc         8G  disk
sdd         8G  disk
sr0      1024M  rom ``

I then use fdisk to partition the empty drives like so:

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`

```
command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/phyisical) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e73dada

      Device Boot        Start            End       Blocks     ld      System
```

I create a 500MB swap partition:

`Command (m for help): n
Partion type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): <RETURN>
using default value 1
First sector (2048-16777215, default 2048):<RETURN>
Using default value 2048
Last sector, *sectors or +size(K,M,G) (2048-16777215, default 16777215): +1Gp`

and want to use the rest for storage:

`Command (m for help): n
Partion type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 2): <RETURN>
using default value 2
First sector (1026048-16777215, default 1026048):<RETURN>
Using default value 1026048
Last sector, *sectors or +size(K,M,G) (2048-16777215, default 16777215):<RETURN>
Using default value 16777215`

The setup now looks like this:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/phyisical) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e73dada

      Device Boot        Start            End       Blocks     ld      System
/dev/sdc1                2048             1026047   512000     83      Linux
/dev/sdc2             1026048            16777215  7875584     83      Linux
```

I then make the 500MB partition into swap space the the 7.5GB partition into bootable space.

`Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-4): 1
Hex code (type L to list codes): 82
Changed system type of partition 1 to 82 (Linux swap / Solaris)`

`Command (m for help): a
Partition number (1-4): 2`

My system now looks like so:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/phyisical) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e73dada

      Device Boot        Start            End       Blocks     ld      System
/dev/sdc1                2048             1026047   512000     82      Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2       *     1026048            16777215  7875584     83      Linux
```

and I write these changes with w

I did the same to sdd so my system looks like so:

`` NAME      SIZE  TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       100G  disk 
|-sda1     10G  part 
|  `-- md0 10G  raid1 [SWAP]
`-sda2     90G  part
   `-- md1 90G  raid1 /
sdb       100G  disk 
|-sdb1     10G  part 
|  `-- md0 10G  raid1 [SWAP]
`-sdb2     90G  part
   `-- md1 90G  raid1 /
sdc         8G  disk
|-sdc1    500M  part 
`-sdc2    7.5G  part
sdd         8G  disk
|-sdd1    500M  part 
`-sdd2    7.5G  part
sr0      1024M  rom ``

I then created a raid array from these partitions with mdadm like so:

`sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md/2 --level=1 /des--raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd`

and I then created an ext4 filesystem on the array

`sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md/2`

Created a mount point like so:

`sudo mkdir -p /media/md2`

and then mounted my completed raid1 array like so:

`sudo mount /dev/md/2 /media/md2`

I then had to use `chmod -R 777 /media/md2`

If I then cd into the mounted partition I see a file called lost+found and am able to write to the drive.

However I then found when I shutdown the virtual machine and restart it the /dev/md/2 is gone and in it's place is dev/md/laz:2.

The virtual machine is called laz.

When I mount it in /media/md2 it still has all the files in, is this all setup ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I then cd into the mounted partition I see a file called lost+found
>   and am able to write to the drive. Have I set everything up correctly?

You must change user owner to `/media/md2` . You can make this with: (This step you make with unmounted drive `sudo umount /media/md2`):

`sudo chown < you_user >:< you_user > /media/md2
 # Example:
sudo chown user:user /media/md2`

And then, when you have folder with your user (check this with: `ls -la /media | grep md2` ), then you can mount your disc into this folder, and write to this disc without sudo .

Comment: thanks, that works great. Any idea why the raid array is changing name upon reboot from /dev/md/2 to /dev/md/laz:2?

Comment: although it seems to work fine so I guess it is not an issue.

Comment: `laz:2` is probably the hostname. You can use `hostname=any` to avoid this